# Calling function in C with array and values are changed?

Tags: c, arrays, function

the code below changes the values of arr in function check and prints out values of "2", even though I didn't pass the array in check function in a pointer. How is that possible?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 void check(int n,int array[]);

 int main()
 {
     int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
     int i;
     check(4,arr);

     for(i=0;i<4;i++){
         printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
     }
     return 0;
 }

 void check(int n,int array[])
 {
     int j=0;

     while(j<n){
         array[j]=2;
         j++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you *did*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`). Beware of undefined behavior.

Comment: Read a good C programming book explaining what are pointers and arrays, what is pointer aliasing, why arrays are decaying into pointers.

Comment: I will not vote to close yet, but not upvote this question.

Comment: So you call a function in C. "Calling a function in C" is *not* your problem. Why don't you use a descriptive topic?

Comment: Because the issue is so relatable with this function! This is my first Q here I'd take your advice in  the next times though!

Comment: I tried to hack up the title a little to something more descriptive

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that

```
void check(int n,int array[]);
```

is the same as

```
void check(int n,int *array);
```

and so, when you use

```
check(4,arr);
```

you are actually doing

```
check(4,&arr[0]); /* This is called array "decay" */
```

and because [array decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/3049655) which points to the address of its first element. So, it means that the "array" is passed by reference.

Comment: thank you! I have another inquiry! When I create a pointer with a zero value in check function and assign it's adress to each of array elements, the arr prints it's original values not zeros. any explanations?

Comment: @BelalFathy I did not understand. Could you show some code?

Answer (score 4):

In C, arrays are converted ("decaying") automatically to pointers when sent to functions.